# SQLite expression maximum depth limit

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sqlite

Enviroment: Cocoa on mac os x Snow Leopard

I have reached the maximum (default) depth for a sqlite query:

```
Expression tree is too large (maximum depth 1000)
```

the sqlite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) say to set the `SQLITE_MAX_EXPR_DEPTH` at compilation, but HOW? i use the default sqlite3 framework, imported with:

```
#import <sqlite3.h>
```

note: i think the maximum expression depth can be lowered (NOT increased) at run-time with:

```
sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_EXPR_DEPTH,size)
```

it's right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about all of your assertions (it's a compile-time setting, it can be lowered not raised at runtime). Your options are to restrict your query or link a custom build of SQLite with your production app.

The good thing about SQLite is that it's pretty simple to build. Read about [custom builds](http://www.sqlite.org/custombuild.html). Also, Apple's SQLite XCode project for OS X 10.6.8 is [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/SQLite/SQLite-74.11/). Whether you use Apple's project or make your own, it's easy to create a shared library to static link into your executable to ship with your project. You will have to worry about compatibility as you release your code, but that's the price you pay for complex queries.

You could also ask about simplifying your complex query in another question.

Comment: BINGO! thank you! auto-answer for posterity :

To solve this problem i use sqlite3 [amalgamation][1] (the ZIP archive contains all C source code for SQLite 3.7.10 combined into a single source file), step:

 1. download end import the sqlite.h and .c in your project
 2. Remove sqlite framework
 3. find SQLITE_MAX_EXPR_DEPTH 1000 in sqlite.c and replace with SQLITE_MAX_EXPR_DEPTH 0

enjoy ;)

  [1]: http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3071000.zip

Answer (score 4):

A simpler solution (although far from perfect).

I had the same error and I had to use Android default's SQLite implementation (querying the system audio database).

The problem appeared as I removed some "useless" parentheses so I put them back, no more error.

Crashes :

```
id = 387 OR id = 388 OR id = 390 OR id = 391 [...] OR id = 392
```

Doesn't crash :

```
(id = 387 OR id = 388 [...] OR id = 390) OR (id = 391 [...] OR id = 392) OR (...
```

I had luck because my parentheses weren't meaningful anyway and could be easily placed.
Not very clean, but it helped to significantly reduce crashes, so I'm happy with it in this case.